# Show that if the partial derivatives of $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, for $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ open and connected, are zero, then $f$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I've been self studying real analysis lately and was trying to solve the following problem from my textbook:

> Show that if the partial derivatives of $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, for $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ open and connected, are zero, then $f$ is constant.

My approach was as follows: If I could prove that $f$ is differentiable just by knowing that its partial derivatives vanish everywhere, then I would be able to prove that $f$ is constant by applying the MVT and using the fact that $U$ is connected and open (hence, poligonally path-connected). To be fair, I wasn't even sure if that was true. I knew that simply having partial derivatives everywhere wasn't enough to guarantee differentiability, but I suspected that the additional condition on the partial derivatives being zero would give us differentiability, so that's what I aimed to prove. I think I managed to give a valid proof, but I was wondering whether someone here could double check it for me. The math started to get a bit messy...
My proof goes as follows:

Since each $\partial f/ \partial x_i=0$, in order to show that $f$ is differentiable, it suffices to prove that, for any $a \in U$, we have
$$\lim_{v \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+v)-f(a)}{|v|}=0.$$
To this end, let $v=(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_m) \in U$ be such that $a+v \in U$, and then notice that

$\displaystyle \begin{align} \frac{f(a+v)-f(a)}{|v|} & = \frac{1}{|v|} \left[\sum_{j=1}^{m-1} |\alpha_j e_j| \cdot \frac{f\left(a+\sum_{i=j}^m \alpha_i e_i \right)-f\left(a+\sum_{i=j+1}^m \alpha_i e_i \right)}{|\alpha_j e_j|} +|\alpha_m e_m| \cdot \frac{f\left(a+\alpha_m e_m \right)-f\left(a\right)}{|\alpha_m e_m|}  \right]   \\ &= \sum_{j=1}^{m-1} \frac{|\alpha_j|}{|v|} \frac{f\left(a+\sum_{i=j}^m \alpha_i e_i \right)-f\left(a+\sum_{i=j+1}^m \alpha_i e_i \right)}{|\alpha_j|} +\frac{|\alpha_m|}{|v|} \frac{f\left(a+\alpha_m e_m \right)-f\left(a\right)}{|\alpha_m|}. \end{align} \tag*{}$

Since all norms are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^m$, we may consider $|v| := \max_{1 \leq k \leq m} \{|\alpha_k|\}$. Therefore,
$$\frac{|\alpha_i|}{|v|}=\frac{|\alpha_i|}{\max_{1 \leq k \leq m} \{|\alpha_k|\}}\leq \frac{|\alpha_i|}{|\alpha_i|}=1.$$
Hence, $\frac{|\alpha_i|}{|v|}$ is bounded as $v \rightarrow 0$ for each $i=1, \dots, m$. This, along with the observation that $v \rightarrow 0 \implies \alpha_i \rightarrow 0$, gives us

$\displaystyle \begin{align} \lim_{v \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+v)-f(a)}{|v|} & \leq \lim_{v \rightarrow 0} \left[\sum_{j=1}^{m-1} \frac{f\left(a+\sum_{i=j}^m \alpha_i e_i \right)-f\left(a+\sum_{i=j+1}^m \alpha_i e_i \right)}{|\alpha_j|} + \frac{f\left(a+\alpha_m e_m \right)-f\left(a\right)}{|\alpha_m|}\right] \\ & = \sum_{j=1}^{m-1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \left(a+ \sum_{i=j}^{m} \alpha_j e_j\right)+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}(a) \\ & = 0  \end{align} \tag*{}$

since the partial derivatives of $f$ vanish everywhere. Thus, $$\lim_{v \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+v)-f(a)}{|v|}=0$$ for every $a \in U$. Equivalently, $f$ is differentiable, which guarantees that its differential is zero, so $f$ is constant.

Comment: A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the partials exist and vanish; i.e they are clearly continuous. This implies $f$ is $C^1$. You can definitely use the mean-value inequality to show immediately that $f$ is constant on every ball (or more generally convex set, or even on a star-shaped open set). To go from here to a general connected set, you use a basic topological fact: a locally constant function on a connected topological space is constant.

It seems like the rest of your argument amounts to reproving a special case of “continuous partial derivatives implies (continuously Frechet) differentiable”, i.e you’re doing unnecessary work.

Comment: Oh, of course. I don't know how I completely missed the fact that the partials are continuous as they are constant (in fact, zero). So the fact that $f \in C^1$ tells us that $f$ is differentiable. Thank you!

Comment: @peek-a-book: Can you state the mean-value inequality that you are referring to?

Comment: @Leonidas Let $V$ be any Banach space, and $f:[a,b]\to V$ a continuous map which is differentiable on $(a,b)$. Then, $\|f(b)-f(a)\|\leq \sup\limits_{t\in (a,b)}\|f’(t)\|\cdot (b-a)$. There are more general versions, and also useful corollaries of this (especially when the domain is an open set in some Banach space) which you can look up, for instance in Loomis-Sternberg, or Henri-Cartan’s *Differential Calculus*.